What is the point of 'else' after a block which ends in 'return'
Is there an advantage to having an 'else' following a block
which ends with a 'return' or is it simply out of habit
int foo (int a)
{
    if(a==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
        if(a==1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    return -1;
}

just curious

It might be considered a good style to have exhaustive handling in the same conditional structure. But it is likely to generate the exact same code.

The last else {} isn't needed. The else clause is always optional for the if statement, it's use is up to the program if it's needed or not.

"What is the point of 'else' after a block which ends in 'return'" --> We enjoy typing.   DRY: int foo (int a) { if(a==0)  { return false;  } if (a==1) { return true; } return -1; }

"I never carry an umbrella. But if it is raining, I will take one with me" versus "If it is raining, I will take an umbrella, otherwise I will not". Both are valid, but some might prefer one over the other based on their style or context it is being said in.

Some programmers apparently think that every if should have an else (either they assume the language requires it or it's good style).

In general, there can be stylistic reasons.  For instance, it may be seen as an advantage to make the lexical structure of the code more consistent with its logical structure.  But I can't think of any good reason for an empty else block anywhere.

In this case, it would make more sense to put return -1 in the else block, to make it clear that this is an exhaustive test.

@JohnBollinger Sometimes the empty blocks can be filled with comments that this case does not have to be handled

Or use switch/case, with return -1; in the default: case.

@EugeneSh., I submit that a block containing comments is not empty (contrast with the OP's code).  However, although I do sometimes document that there is nothing to do when an if condition is not satisfied, and why, I personally do that without adding an actual else clause to the if.

completely <O/T>, I know functionally all the same, but mixing the bool and int returns types looks odd IMO. Would prefer to stick to one type, and in this case make that if (a == 0 || a == 1) return a; /*else*/ return -1;

This is purely a style choice, or perhaps a misunderstanding that else is required for every if.
If all the if blocks contain return, there's no technical difference between putting the remaining code in a final else block or putting it after the final else if block in the chain; the same code should be generated. And an empty else block has no effect at all.
Some programmers may prefer to use the else block for stylistic reasons, it makes the parallel structure clear.
There's also no technical reason to use else if when all the if blocks return. There are some proponents of "else-less" programming who would write the above function as
int foo (int a)
{
    if(a==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(a==1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return -1;
}

On the other hand, many programmers prefer a chain of else if to make it clear that these are mutually exclusive conditions. Then you don't have to look into the bodies to see that they all return.

I've updated the answer, maybe this gets at the gist of the question better.

Everyone has their way of writing code, but I think your code here is a significantly easier read.

"don't have to look into the bodies to see that they all return." Erh... Disregarding flow of control -- relying on the layout of code -- is almost always a bad idea. The OP's is a perfect example. Two "early returns" (are they there?) and a null else body, before some "common" processing (in this case: /* stuff; stuff; */ return -1;) if/elseif/else, mixed with a smattering of early returns, is a recipe for disaster...

@Fe2O3 If you don't format your code for easy reading, it doesn't really matter how you code it, it will be difficult to understand. That's why one of the first things I do when I'm reading a poorly-formatted SO question is fix the indentation.

@Barmar 100% agreement from me. That's why promotion of dogmatic adherence to some "style spec" or "best practice" gives me tummy upset... A haiku is not a sonnet. Likewise, there are too many zealots who mandate distorting code to align with one rigid "style", where the other (or even freeform) should have been recognised as more appropriate.

@Fe2O3 What matters isn't which style you adhere to, but that the code is consistent.

@Barmar "Consistent"? Or, "expressive"? This long answer of mine has 4 "chapters". Not every day one encounters code looking like the cmp() function in the 3rd chapter ("On-The-Fly scaling of data"). imo, "adherence" (to a 'style' or a 'norm') acts contrary to prioritising clarity (and correctness, of course.) I presume the reader to have an aptitude sufficient to scan & parse reasonably quickly... (Fixed, today, this answer. Two years, and no-one had remarked on its deficiency. Hmmm...)

One place where not using else makes sense with a return is writing code which uses a conditional as a sentinel that returns as soon as a fault condition is noted.
Consider a program which dynamically allocates an array of ints and initializes it. If the allocation fails, we want to return NULL. We could write the following.
int *array(size_t n) {
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    if (!arr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation of %zu ints failed.\n", n);
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }

        return arr;
    }
}

Or, leaving out the extraneous else because if the if condition is true, control flow skips past the rest of the function body anyway.
int *array(size_t n) {
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    if (!arr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation of %zu ints failed.\n", n);
        return NULL;
    }
   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    return arr;
}

The latter removes a level of indentation which likely doesn't matter here, but might if the code within the else block contained even more levels of indentation. Generally the more levels you go deep, the harder it becomes to keep track of what's going on in your head as you read the code.
